# How to get class / method / method parameters information at the carret position in a document programmatically in my own vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Let say I'm in a c++ file, and want to get all available information programmatically from c++ parser (class name, method name, method parameters) related to a provided position in the active c++ document. The provided position will be equal to caret position.

In short I want to access the same information that the code completion / show documentation accesses.

After reading the VSCode API docs, my understanding is that the code completion feature makes some request to the c++ Language Server and the Language Server responds with all known information about the requested position in the document.

I found the Signature Help Request API method.

> The signature help request is sent from the client to the server to
> request signature information at a given cursor position.

https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/specification#textDocument_signatureHelp

How can I make Signature Help Request to the currently used Language Server by the document?
Is it the right method to get class name, method name, method parameters of at the caret line?